# Error: Attempt to apply non-function using for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm relatively new to programming of any kind, and my supervisor has given me a large dataset, which he wants me to perform a Fisher's Exact test on each of the datapoints to check for significance. He wants me to use a For loop to do this, and to pipe the resulting P value from each datapoint into a new variable. I've tried doing this, however, I keep getting the same error code every time, and I can't figure out how to fix it. Here is the code I've been using:

```
for(i in 1:23633(data)) {
  temp_case_del = data$case_del[i]
  temp_con_del = data$con_del[i]
  F_data <- matrix(c(temp_case_del, 5648, temp_con_del, 8414),
                    nrow = 2,
                    ncol = 2,)
  PVal[i] <- fisher.test(F_data)$p.value
```

Any help to fix this issue would be much appreciated.

Comment: have you tried with : `for(i in 1:23633)` (without `(data)`)

Comment: Or `for (i in seq_along(data)) {`...

Comment: Both of those worked, thank you! The error message is now gone, however, the loop doesn't appear to be working. I am only getting the p value of 1, and the F_data matrix contains the values 5648, 8414, 5648, 8414. Any idea why the loop is not working?